# Does making multiple web requests in C# asynchronously faster then making them synchronously?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, synchronous

In a scenario that you have a limited amount of time to make multiple web requests will it be better to do them asynchronously or synchronously?
Edit: by a limited amount of time I meant a limited amount of time for the code to run

Comment: Well, how many requests are we talking about here? If it's just a few, the overhead is most likely not worth it.

Comment: Run the code, time it, and find out for yourself which of your implementations is faster.

Comment: "you have a limited amount of time to make multiple web requests" - is it some sort of coding competition? I'd say go for synchronous code - it is generally easier to get right and you need to tune defaults to get significant benefits of parallel requests...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov They might mean a limited amount of time for the code to run (Maybe they have, say, 2 minutes to perform all of the web requests), rather than a limited time for the code to be written.  While it is indeed ambiguous, the wording to me doesn't suggest time to develop the code as what's being asked about.

Comment: neither will be better. you can send out thousands of requests in very short time in parallel and get 98% of timeouts. is it better? so, as Servy pointed out, you cant get around measuring your specific case and knowing much more details about your requess than you provided.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET HTTP implementation can perform pipelining if you make concurrent requests to it, so if you're making idempotent requests it might have better throughput.

Comment: How do you do that?